# JSR-380 Validation on a List<Comparable>

Tags: java, validation

Is it possible to create a custom JSR-380 Validation that operates on a List of objects that implement the Comparable Interface?  I want to create a validation like "@Ordered" to ensure that a list passed into a method is in a particular order.

Example:

```
public void foo (@Ordered List<BigDecimal> aList) {
}
```

Comment: It's nice to want things, but have you actually tried anything? At all?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying a few things and reading about creating List based validators.  I can create one that looks at each member of the list individually, but not as a whole collection to do comparisons of each element in relation to the other elements.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your attempts, you could get help on the issues you are having. Right now it looks like you are asking for free code.

Comment: You will get more answers if you use a name instead of a number.  Few people know off the top of their heads what JSR 380 is, but many know what Bean Validation is.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=SequenceValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Sequence {
  String message () default "Sequence is not valid.";
  Class<?>[] groups() default { };
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

And then...

```
public class SequenceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Sequence, List<? extends Comparable<?>>> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Sequence seq) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<? extends Comparable<?>> values, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
        System.out.println ("Validating: " + values);
        return values == null || Ordering.natural().isOrdered(values);
    }
```